# Can't Access CIMC

Tags: configuration-management, cisco-ucs

I have a Cisco UCS C220 M3, and it has the Flash/Java-based CIMC interface. When getting Flash, the only versions are for Chromium-based browsers and Mozilla-based browsers. However, neither of those browsers support Java anymore, according to [this](https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml) Java page, leaving only Internet Explorer. However, that does not support flash. So how do I access CIMC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CIMC should launch with Java Web Start, but Oracle deprecated this in Oracle Java 9 and removed it in Oracle Java 11. Oracle offered no replacement technology.

You have a couple of options:

- Use a (virtual) machine with the older version of Oracle Java installed.
- Use IcedTea-Web, which is the OpenJDK reimplementation of Java Web Start. You'll generally get this by default if you install Java provided by the Linux distributor, and it should work out of the box.

As for Flash, you're screwed. Nobody ships that anymore and for good reason; Adobe has abandoned it years ago. Your only option there is to run a virtual machine with an ancient OS that still has Flash, and pray that it doesn't get broken into.

Comment: I ended  up using an old version of flash and using java web start, thanks!